# Lodash debounce not working

Tags: javascript, lodash

`const { debounce } = require('lodash');`

```
debounce(
   () => {
     console.log('testing..');
   },
  1000,
  { leading: true, trailing: false }
);
```

The above code does not work.
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce
All the examples in the docs use named functions.
Is there an issue with using Loash debounce with anonymous function?

Comment: What exactly does "does not work" mean in this context?

Comment: Actually denounce returns a fn which when called will call the inner fn after specified time duration

Comment: means the opposite of 'works' :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why is the variable name in braces?

At any rate, lodash's debounce function is a higher order function and will return a debounced function. So you should use it like this.

```
const debounce = require('lodash/debounce');
const debouncedFunction = debounce(() => {
    console.log('debounced')
}, 1000)
```

EDIT: Just wanted to note that the braces are for destructuring the require, and are valid syntax. This is good for libraries that don't implement the `<library>/<property>` as lodash does.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, it doesn't work, because you don't call it.
add `()` before `;` - and it will work

Comment: this should be the answer :)