# Lodash's debounce and vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, lodash, pinia

I'm having an issue with debounce from lodash and vue3, could you help me find the issue in this code please?

**Pinia's Store**

```
actions: {
    fetchUsers(targetAppId?: string) {
      this.loading = true;
      AppsService.getUsers(targetAppId)
        .then(response => {
          this.users = response.data.users
          // This statement works without debounce
          debounce(() => { this.loading = false }, 1000)
        })
    },
  }
```

Comment: I think the issue is that debounce returns a function, which then needs calling, which you're not doing here. You could try something as simple as adding `()`, like `debounce(() => { this.loading = false }, 1000)()`. There's plenty of similar threads on SO eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033621/lodash-debounce-not-working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306290/lodash-debounce-not-working-in-anonymous-function and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47809666/lodash-debounce-not-working-in-react are the same ... some dupe merging needed perhaps!

Comment: @sifriday but if I do like so, the statement is triggered automatically with not debouncing at all

Comment: show us how did you add loadash to your project please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will never work the way u want it to.

it's like `sifriday` said, `debounce` returns a (new) function and you would need to re-call that function for a correct working debounce. but in your store you have an anonymous function, so there's no reference to actually debounce it.

you could add a `loading` state & then do a debounce on a `commit` which toggles this state OR wrap the action itself in a debounce.